# C# How can I use an interface to clear a variable value from a different class?

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to learn about interfaces and abstract classes. I have a base Account class, a child class for PersonalAccounts, a child class for BusinessAccounts an IPayMyBill interface, and a main. I need to use the accounts to output the account info (Names, addresses, amountDue, invoiceDate, DueDate)and after this info is output, I must call the pay method of the interface on each instance of the classes to set the amountDue to 0. Could someone explain how to do this, or link me some resources that will help me figure it out?

Here is my code so far,base Account:

```
abstract class Account : IPayMyBill
{

    private String _address;
    private Decimal _amountDue;
    private DateTime _invoiceDate;

    public Account(String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate)
    {
        Address = address;
        AmountDue = amountDue;
        InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;

    }
    public String Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
    public Decimal AmountDue
    {
        get { return _amountDue; }
        set { _amountDue = value; }
    }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate
    {
        get { return _invoiceDate; }
        set { _invoiceDate = value; }
    }
    public abstract DateTime DueDate
    {
        get;
    }
    public void Pay()
    {

    }



}
```

child 1:

```
class PersonalAccounts : Account , IPayMyBill
{
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;

    public PersonalAccounts(String firstName, String lastName, String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate ) : base(address, amountDue, invoiceDate, DueDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public String LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
    public override DateTime DueDate 
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);}
    }
    public void Pay()
    {
       //not sure how to code this
    }
}
```

child 2:

```
class BusinessAccounts : Account, IPayMyBill
{
    private String _businessName;

    public BusinessAccounts(String businessName, String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate) : base(address, amountDue, invoiceDate, DueDate)
    {
        BusinessName = businessName;
    }
    public String BusinessName
    {
        get { return _businessName; }
        set { _businessName = value; }
    }
    public override DateTime DueDate 
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(60); }
    }
    public void Pay()
    {
        //Not sure how to code this
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IPayMyBill
{
    void Pay();
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PersonalAccounts PA = new PersonalAccounts("Andy", "Smith", "123 Hope St.", 500M, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(30));

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + PA.FirstName + " " + PA.LastName + string.Format(" Amount Due: {0:C2}", PA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + PA.DueDate.ToString("d"));

        BusinessAccounts BA = new BusinessAccounts("Sam's Scooters", "456 Lost Ave.", 700M, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(60));

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + BA.BusinessName + " " + string.Format("Amount Due: {0:C2}", BA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + BA.DueDate.ToString("d"));


        //I want to reset the Amount Due here, but don't know how.

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write Pay method in Child classes.

Your abstract Account class has inherit the IPayMyBill, just write the reset code in Account.Pay() method.

```
void Main()
{

    PersonalAccounts PA = new PersonalAccounts("Andy", "Smith", "123 Hope St.", 500M, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(30));

    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + PA.FirstName + " " + PA.LastName + string.Format(" Amount Due: {0:C2}", PA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + PA.DueDate.ToString("d"));

    BusinessAccounts BA = new BusinessAccounts("Sam's Scooters", "456 Lost Ave.", 700M, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(60));

    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + BA.BusinessName + " " + string.Format("Amount Due: {0:C2}", BA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + BA.DueDate.ToString("d"));


    //I want to reset the Amount Due here, but don't know how.
    PA.Pay();
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + PA.FirstName + " " + PA.LastName + string.Format(" Amount Due: {0:C2}", PA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + PA.DueDate.ToString("d"));
    BA.Pay();
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + BA.BusinessName + " " + string.Format("Amount Due: {0:C2}", BA.AmountDue) + " Due: " + BA.DueDate.ToString("d"));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
abstract class Account : IPayMyBill
{

    private String _address;
    private Decimal _amountDue;
    private DateTime _invoiceDate;

    public Account(String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate)
    {
        Address = address;
        AmountDue = amountDue;
        InvoiceDate = invoiceDate;

    }
    public String Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
    public Decimal AmountDue
    {
        get { return _amountDue; }
        set { _amountDue = value; }
    }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate
    {
        get { return _invoiceDate; }
        set { _invoiceDate = value; }
    }
    public abstract DateTime DueDate
    {
        get;
    }
    public void Pay()
    {
        this.AmountDue = 0;
    }
}

class PersonalAccounts : Account, IPayMyBill
{
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;

    public PersonalAccounts(String firstName, String lastName, String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate) : base(address, amountDue, invoiceDate, DueDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public String LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
    public override DateTime DueDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(30); }
    }
}
class BusinessAccounts : Account, IPayMyBill
{
    private String _businessName;

    public BusinessAccounts(String businessName, String address, Decimal amountDue, DateTime invoiceDate, DateTime DueDate) : base(address, amountDue, invoiceDate, DueDate)
    {
        BusinessName = businessName;
    }
    public String BusinessName
    {
        get { return _businessName; }
        set { _businessName = value; }
    }
    public override DateTime DueDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(60); }
    }
}

public interface IPayMyBill
{
    void Pay();
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you say like abstract class with pay() abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the other answers

No interface is required, if you would like to have control over pay functionality from the Derived classes

```
abstract class Account
{
   // you are forcing all Derived classes to implement their own functionality 
   public abstract void Pay();
}

public class Child : Account
{        
    public override void Pay()
    {
        // implement child pay functionality here 
    }
}
```

`public abstract void Pay();` just forces the Derived Class to implement this

You would use an interface if you didn't have the abstract class or you wanted to use methods and properties that aren't available in the base class

Or if the functionality you want to implement in pay is all available in the base class you could just create the method there which all Derived class will natively have.

Lastly you could use a Virtual method

```
abstract class Account
{
   public virtual void Pay()
   {
       // code which may or may not be overridden by the inheritor 
   }
}

// this class just implements the default pay behaviour
public class Child1 : Account
{
}

// this class overrides the default pay behaviour
public class Child2 : Account
{
   public virtual void Pay()
   {
       // Add your own custom pay functionality 
   }
}

// this class calls the default pay behaviour and does other things
public class Child3 : Account
{
   //other stuff
   public virtual void Pay()
   {
       // calls the default pay implementation in base class 
       base.Pay();

       // Add your additional pay functionality 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered sufficiently if the functionality is the same across all child classes by putting it into the base, but I didn't see anything regarding if the functionality needs to be differently implemented per child. In that case you would want to declare the variables in the base class as `protected` rather than `private` - from [protected (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected):

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class
>   instances.

That means you could do something like this:

```
abstract class Account : IPayMyBill
{
    private String _address;
    protected Decimal _amountDue;
    private DateTime _invoiceDate;
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
class PersonalAccounts : Account , IPayMyBill
{
    ...
    public void Pay()
    {
        // This will work because child classes can access protected members from their base class and _amountDue was declared above as protected
        _amountDue = 0;
    }

    public void ChangeAddress(string newAddress)
    {
        // This won't work because _address is private so can't be accessed by the child class
        _address = newAddress;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Prettified the quote from microsoft docs